Problem installing UFT because of not having Media features
In installing UFT I get asked to installe Microsoft Media Features. As far as I can see they have been installed and activated. Did anyone encounter this problem?

Are there some further media features I have to install? This is unfortunately no specified.

Are you installing UFT One or UFT Developer?

I try to install UFT Developer

After all, your comment sovled my problem. I tried to install UFT One, ran into the same problem, but it offererd me to install without AI Features and it worked.

Good to hear, still strange that it wasn't satisfied by your Media Features...
